# Running tests on browserstack throws "Cannot read property 'capabilities' of null"

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io, browserstack

I am running tests using wdioV5 and browserstack but I am getting the following error:

`ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: TypeError: Cannot read property 'capabilities' of null`

I tried to check the debug logs but unable to figure the reasoning behind it, has anyone faced a similar issue?

DEBUG output:

```
[0-0] 2019-06-06T13:34:00.454Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 3/3
[0-0] 2019-06-06T13:34:00.455Z INFO webdriver: [POST] https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com:443/session
[0-0] 2019-06-06T13:34:00.455Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities: 
   { alwaysMatch: 
      { os: 'Windows',
        os_version: '10',
        browser: 'Chrome',
        browser_version: '73.0',
        'browserstack.local': true },
     firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities: 
   { os: 'Windows',
     os_version: '10',
     browser: 'Chrome',
     browser_version: '73.0',
     'browserstack.local': true } }
[0-0] 2019-06-06T13:34:00.480Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to status 13
[0-0] 2019-06-06T13:34:00.481Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to Error: Session not started or terminated
```

If it helps reproduce, my config is:

```
 path: '/',
  specs: [ './specs/**/*.js' ],
  exclude: [],
  maxInstances: 10,
  capabilities: 
   [ { os: 'Windows',
       os_version: '10',
       browser: 'Chrome',
       browser_version: '73.0' } ],
  logLevel: 'trace',
  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: [ 'browserstack' ],
  framework: 'mocha',
  reporters: [ 'spec' ],
  mochaOpts: { timeout: 60000 },
  before: [Function: before],
  user: 'xxx',
  key: 'xxx',
  browserstackLocal: true,
  onPrepare: [Function: onPrepare],
  onComplete: [Function: onComplete] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... for some reason, having this option in the `wdio.conf.js` threw the error message above, the moment I removed it, it worked, which is mad:

`path: '/'`

Comment: if you're using browserstack, changing the path with mess up where the commands are sent to. Not too mad for that sort of thing to happen.

Comment: if the path is empty `path: ''` it also fails... which is why I thought it wasn't used at all...

Comment: The default path value is `/wd/hub`, which is appended to your host value (default of `http://localhost:4444`, which altogether becomes `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`). If you set `path: ''`, it doesn't use the default and becomes just `http://localhost:4444`.